# Set Default Application Handler in Firefox 60 ESR with a script

Tags: firefox, tel

How could I set a custom executable to the TEL: protocol in Firefox 60 and above?

In older versions I could do this by copying an already edited mimeTypes.rdf to the default Firefox profile.

Since Firefox 60 it looks like this file is not used anymore.

Any idea how are the default apps configured and how could I make this change with a script in the current releases of the browser?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I looked it up in my own profiles folder and it seems like the file is now called *handlers.json* and is found under:

*C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profilename>.default\handlers.json*